# How to see the latest apps released in the App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore

I seem to remember that you could view the latest apps/games released in any category of the App Store. I used to love trying out new games and you could usually find a few gems that you otherwise wouldn’t be able to find.

So is there anyway of finding an true list of the latest released apps/games? And if there is, is there a way to find a list of latest releases within a certain category (such as the latest action games). The closest I could find is ‘new games we love’ in store and in the RSS feed.

Also I have seen a section in the App Store for ‘pre-orders’ but have never found the section since (it was one the main page of the App Store with the apps of the week etc) any ideas on how to find this again would also be a massive help!

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't show a list of new apps or games. However, you can use a third-party site like [148apps.com](https://www.148apps.com/newest-148-app-store-additions/) to view the newest apps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the only way is to buy the bundle from time to time and match for discrepancies
https://42matters.com/app-market-data

And what RSS feed did you mention? Can I get the link to check if it is still alive.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/321804)